# Weird behavior of longtable

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a fairly long longtable in my document that does this weird thing:
[image: weird page split]

Basically, it adds that little (vertical) divider after the table has finished (I know I have two hlines, but that is not a problem atm). Anyone know how to fix this?

Relevant code:

```
\begin{longtable}{p{1.7cm} | p{1.5cm} p{1.5cm} p{1.5cm} p{1.5cm} p{1.5cm}  p{1.5cm}}
...
\hline
$\bar{R^2}$ & .6298 & .6273 & .6277 & .6255 & .6459 & .5810 \\
$N$ & 149 & 149 & 149 & 149 & 149 & 85 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize{${}^{***}$ significant at 1\% level, ${}^{**}$ significant at 5\% level, ${}^*$ significant at 10\% level}} \\
\hline
\hline
\label{regmodels}
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Move the `\label` to a better place. It starts a cell.

Answer (score 3):

The `\label` starts a cell.  Move it to a better place (e.g. in an existing cell).